# Trying to post to a form that uses frames and retrieve the data using python

Tags: python, post, python-requests, multipartform-data, frames

Thanks to Northcat and others, I was able to post a multipart/form-data request to http://www.camp.bicnirrh.res.in/featcalc/ using requests - and it worked like a charm. I'm now trying to POST data to http://pro-161-70.ib.unicamp.br/~itaraju/tools/pimw/ and select just the "Show pI/MW values" options. I'm uploading a file called Denovo. This is what I've been trying so far, trying to follow the same format that worked from my earlier posted question.

```
import requests
import urllib
session = requests.Session()
file={'file': (open('Bishop/Denovo.txt', 'r').read())}
url = 'http://pro-161-70.ib.unicamp.br/~itaraju/tools/pimw/pimw.htm'
payload = {"opShowpimw":"opShowpimw", "opUseTabs":"opUseTabs"}
raw = urllib.urlencode(payload)
response = session.post(url, files=file, data=payload)
print response.text
```

I'm using the url in the code rather than the one listed at the top because the website uses frames and returns 'This page uses frames, but your browser doesn\'t support them'. So I found the url above by viewing the 'view frame source'. The payload was from looking at ieheaders. The first one in payload corresponds to the "Show pI/MW values" and the second was a shot in the dark trying to make it easier by making it come out as text (on the form, click '.txt format). The response doesn't have values in it, and comes out looking like the first page. The url for the frame source on the results page is this 'http://pro-161-70.ib.unicamp.br/~itaraju/cgi-bin/itaraju/bioinf/pimw.cgi', however, using this yields no response.

Comment: You don't need POST to `pimw.htm` - it does nothing. You have to POST to `pimw.cgi` - and you have to post all fields avaliable on `pimw.htm`

Comment: Hi sorry, but the response I get back after using all the parameters, as shown in the post below, yields no data. I'm doing everything the same in the above post, except changing the url to the -pimw.cgi and changing my payload to what's below, but the response is 1600 characters with no data in it. Do you know why this might be? I don't actually need the images, I just need the numbers. Thanks.

Comment: `pimw.htm` shows only form. You have to send data to `pimw.cgi` because `pimw.cgi` generates results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I send sequence as text in `tbSeq`

I found this sequence on http://pro-161-70.ib.unicamp.br/~itaraju/tools/pimw/what.htm

It gives me some results and image (as below) saved od disk as `'output.gif'`.

```
import requests
import lxml.html

url = 'http://pro-161-70.ib.unicamp.br/~itaraju/cgi-bin/itaraju/bioinf/pimw.cgi'
payload = {
    'arquivo': '',
    'opShowTitle': 'ON',
    'opShowSeq': 'ON',
    'opShowStat': 'ON',
    'opShowpimw': 'ON',
    'opGelVirtual': 'ON',
    'opMap': 'gel0.def',
    'opPK': 'Default',
    'tbCt': 3.55,
    'tbNt': 7,
    'tbArg': 12.01,
    'tbAsp': 4.06,
    'tbCys': 9,
    'tbGlu': 4.45,
    'tbHis': 5.985,
    'tbLys': 10.01,
    'tbTyr': 10.01,
    'tbSeq': '''>gi|532319|pir|TVFV2E|TVFV2E envelope protein
ELRLRYCAPAGFALLKCNDADYDGFKTNCSNVSVVH
CTNLMNTTVTTGLLLNGSYSENRTQIWQKHRTSNDS
ALILLNKHYNLTVTCKRPGNKTVLPVTIMAGLVFHSQ
KYNLRLRQAWCHFPSNWKGAWKEVKEEIVNLPKER
YRGTNDPKRIFFQRQWGDPETANLWFNCHGEFFYCK
MDWFLNYLNNLTVDADHNECKNTSGTKSGNKRAPG
PCVQRTYVACHIRSVIIWLETISKKTYAPPREGHLECT
STVTGMTVELNYIPKNRTNVTLSPQIESIWAAELDRY
KLVEITPIGFAPTEVRRYTGGHERQKRVPFVXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXVQSQHLLAGILQQQKNL
LAAVEAQQQMLKLTIWGVK''',
}

# send POST    
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

#print r.text

# convert HTML string into HTML tree
html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)

# get all images
imgs = html.cssselect('img')

# get second image
if len(imgs) > 1:
    url = 'http://pro-161-70.ib.unicamp.br/~itaraju/cgi-bin/itaraju/bioinf/' + imgs[1].attrib['src'].strip()

    print "Downloading ...",  url

    with open('output.gif', 'wb') as handle:
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

        if not r.ok:
            # Something went wrong
            pass

        for block in r.iter_content(1024):
            if not block:
                break

            handle.write(block)
            print '.',

        print 

# get data
for tr in html.cssselect('tr'):
    for td in tr.cssselect('tr'):
        print td.text_content().strip().replace('\n', ' | '),
    print
```

Result:

```
Downloading ... http://pro-161-70.ib.unicamp.br/~itaraju/cgi-bin/itaraju/bioinf/../../../tools/htdocs/tmp/gel.15548.gif
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .


ORF:
gi|532319|pir|TVFV2E|TVFV2E envelope protein
Sequence:
ELRLRYCAPAGFALLKCNDADYDGFKTNCS NVSVVHCTNLMNTTVTTGLLLNGSYSENRT QIWQKHRTSNDSALILLNKHYNLTVTCKRP GNKTVLPVTIMAGLVFHSQKYNLRLRQAWC HFPSNWKGAWKEVKEEIVNLPKERYRGTND PKRIFFQRQWGDPETANLWFNCHGEFFYCK MDWFLNYLNNLTVDADHNECKNTSGTKSGN KRAPGPCVQRTYVACHIRSVIIWLETISKK TYAPPREGHLECTSTVTGMTVELNYIPKNR TNVTLSPQIESIWAAELDRYKLVEITPIGF APTEVRRYTGGHERQKRVPFVXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXVQSQHLLAGILQQQKNL LAAVEAQQQMLKLTIWGVK
MW: |       pI:
40969.02 |  |   9.35
Amino-acid composition
Ala (A) | 20 | 5.3% |  | Cys (C) | 12 | 3.2% |  | Asp (D) | 10 | 2.6% |  | Glu (E) | 19 | 5.0% |  | Phe (F) | 12 | 3.2% |  | Gly (G) | 20 | 5.3% |  | His (H) | 11 | 2.9% |  | Ile (I) | 16 | 4.2% |  | Lys (K) | 24 | 6.3% |  | Leu (L) | 34 | 9.0% |  |    |  |  | Met (M) | 5 | 1.3% |  | Asn (N) | 27 | 7.1% |  | Pro (P) | 16 | 4.2% |  | Gln (Q) | 17 | 4.5% |  | Arg (R) | 21 | 5.5% |  | Ser (S) | 16 | 4.2% |  | Thr (T) | 30 | 7.9% |  | Val (V) | 24 | 6.3% |  | Trp (W) | 10 | 2.6% |  | Tyr (Y) | 13 | 3.4% Ala (A) | 20 | 5.3% Cys (C) | 12 | 3.2% Asp (D) | 10 | 2.6% Glu (E) | 19 | 5.0% Phe (F) | 12 | 3.2% Gly (G) | 20 | 5.3% His (H) | 11 | 2.9% Ile (I) | 16 | 4.2% Lys (K) | 24 | 6.3% Leu (L) | 34 | 9.0% Met (M) | 5 | 1.3% Asn (N) | 27 | 7.1% Pro (P) | 16 | 4.2% Gln (Q) | 17 | 4.5% Arg (R) | 21 | 5.5% Ser (S) | 16 | 4.2% Thr (T) | 30 | 7.9% Val (V) | 24 | 6.3% Trp (W) | 10 | 2.6% Tyr (Y) | 13 | 3.4%
Ala (A) | 20 | 5.3%
Cys (C) | 12 | 3.2%
Asp (D) | 10 | 2.6%
Glu (E) | 19 | 5.0%
Phe (F) | 12 | 3.2%
Gly (G) | 20 | 5.3%
His (H) | 11 | 2.9%
Ile (I) | 16 | 4.2%
Lys (K) | 24 | 6.3%
Leu (L) | 34 | 9.0%
Met (M) | 5 | 1.3%
Asn (N) | 27 | 7.1%
Pro (P) | 16 | 4.2%
Gln (Q) | 17 | 4.5%
Arg (R) | 21 | 5.5%
Ser (S) | 16 | 4.2%
Thr (T) | 30 | 7.9%
Val (V) | 24 | 6.3%
Trp (W) | 10 | 2.6%
Tyr (Y) | 13 | 3.4%
Total:  | 379
Theoretical 2D gel:
```

Small red dot :)

[image]

---

**EDIT:** example with file - file have to be send in field named `arquivo`

```
import requests
import lxml.html

url = 'http://pro-161-70.ib.unicamp.br/~itaraju/cgi-bin/itaraju/bioinf/pimw.cgi'
payload = {
#    'arquivo': '', # remove it
    'opShowTitle': 'ON',
    'opShowSeq': 'ON',
    'opShowStat': 'ON',
    'opShowpimw': 'ON',
    'opGelVirtual': 'ON',
    'opMap': 'gel0.def',
    'opPK': 'Default',
    'tbCt': 3.55,
    'tbNt': 7,
    'tbArg': 12.01,
    'tbAsp': 4.06,
    'tbCys': 9,
    'tbGlu': 4.45,
    'tbHis': 5.985,
    'tbLys': 10.01,
    'tbTyr': 10.01,
    'tbSeq': '',
}

files = {'arquivo': open('sequence.fasta').read()}

#url = 'http://httpbin.org/post' # special portal for tests

# send POST    
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, files=files)

#print r.text

# convert HTML string into HTML tree
html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)

# get all images
imgs = html.cssselect('img')

# get second image
if len(imgs) > 1:
    url = 'http://pro-161-70.ib.unicamp.br/~itaraju/cgi-bin/itaraju/bioinf/' + imgs[1].attrib['src'].strip()

    print "Downloading ...",  url

    with open('output.gif', 'wb') as handle:
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

        if not r.ok:
            # Something went wrong
            pass

        for block in r.iter_content(1024):
            if not block:
                break

            handle.write(block)
            print '.',

        print 

# get data
for tr in html.cssselect('tr'):
    for td in tr.cssselect('tr'):
        print td.text_content().strip().replace('\n', ' | '),
    print
```

Used file `sequence.fasta`

```
>gi|532319|pir|TVFV2E|TVFV2E envelope protein
ELRLRYCAPAGFALLKCNDADYDGFKTNCSNVSVVH
CTNLMNTTVTTGLLLNGSYSENRTQIWQKHRTSNDS
ALILLNKHYNLTVTCKRPGNKTVLPVTIMAGLVFHSQ
KYNLRLRQAWCHFPSNWKGAWKEVKEEIVNLPKER
YRGTNDPKRIFFQRQWGDPETANLWFNCHGEFFYCK
MDWFLNYLNNLTVDADHNECKNTSGTKSGNKRAPG
PCVQRTYVACHIRSVIIWLETISKKTYAPPREGHLECT
STVTGMTVELNYIPKNRTNVTLSPQIESIWAAELDRY
KLVEITPIGFAPTEVRRYTGGHERQKRVPFVXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXVQSQHLLAGILQQQKNL
LAAVEAQQQMLKLTIWGVK
```

Comment: r = requests.post(url, files=file, data=payload). I ran this, and the print r.text yielded, as mentioned before, no actual data. Any ideas why would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't send data in FASTA format (because I have it) so I got only empty image.

Comment: I changed example - I send some sequence as text (not as file) and I get some results.

Comment: I made example with file. File have to be send in field named `arquivo`.

Comment: Thank you! I actually got it to work by opening, reading, and closing the file (saving as data) and putting it into the 'tbSeq' field